# Using Grunt on Heroku without defiling devDependencies

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, sass, gruntjs

I understand, in general, the most frequent way Grunt is used on Heroku -- load the buildpack, specify your `grunt heroku` task(s), and include any Grunt plugins you want to use on the Heroku dyno in your `package.json:dependencies.`

However, I find this to be a rather poor solution, because it miscommunicates about my app. My Grunt plugins are all more like `devDependencies`, as I will only run anything with Grunt one time (per deploy). My app doesn't directly depend on them to run, as it's mostly minification and template compilation.

I'm also trying to keep compiled files (e.g. `.css` and `.html` files when I'm writing in Sass and Handlebars) out of source control, so pushing them over from Github is possible but definitely not what I want.

Is there a way to do all of the following?

- exclude `.css` and `.html` files from Git
- write stylesheets and markup using Sass and Handlebars
- push a basic Express app containing these files to Heroku
- have Heroku run a server-relative version of my `grunt build` task (naming it whatever is necessary is fine) to compile and prepare all of the views and assets before launching the `web:` process
- have Heroku's Grunt task intelligently understand that I just want some pre-launch compilation so it will look at `devDependencies` and install the relevant ones in a perhaps-temporary kind of way
- launch the Express server via the `web:` process

I'm fine with having to write my own buildpack, or whatever needs to be done to do this (what I perceive to be) the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I created the buildpack [heroku-buildpack-webapp-client](https://github.com/djng/heroku-buildpack-webapp-client) that supports grunt, compass/sass and installs your `devDependencies`. Maybe you can use this one or have a look at the [`bin/compile` script](https://github.com/djng/heroku-buildpack-webapp-client/blob/master/bin/compile) to see how it works.